# Where to ask for an acronym?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a well-known military acronym (like KIA, SOP, or POW) ending with a specific letter. I've went through a rather long list of acronyms, but none are really well-known (or unambiguous).

However, I don't think EL&U is a really a good fit for this kind of question, is it? And if not, where should I go?

Comment: You could try the chat rooms. Some of the chatters like wordplay and this sounds kind of puzzlelike.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Thanks for the input; [I went ahead and created a room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23383/military-acronym-ending-with-c) for that (although I did mess up the formatting quite horribly).